# What is the term for the "naive" or "null" case?

Tags: terminology

What is the term for the "naive" or "null" case for something? It's like when you have a general rule for something, but a definition or a special case for the case where you're dealing with something degenerative, like the null set, or infinity, or zero, or something. It's *almost* like a "base case" in induction, but you're not using it to infer anything else.

Comment: *Trivial case* is one answer, but you need to be more specific. Do you have some nice example?

Comment: "Trivial case"? "Degenerate case"? Depends on what exactly makes it stand out.

Comment: There is [tag:terminology] tag.

Comment: @DietrichBurde THAT'S IT! This has been bugging me all morning!

Comment: @Vepir thanks for letting me know about the terminology tag.